# Approximation of a factorial

Tags: reference-request, approximation, factorial, gamma-function

In books I can find a lot of approximations of factorial, which doesn't require the a lot of multiplications, like for example Stirling's approximation. Very popular is also the Euler's solution which is:
$$
n! = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^n\cdot k!}{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)}, \qquad k\in \Bbb N.
$$
When can I found explanation how this derive the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Following the wikipedia entry on the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), the formula is obtained  from
$$
n!=n\cdot(n-1)!=n\cdot\Gamma(n).
$$

If $k>n$, then
$$
\frac{k^n⋅k!}{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)}=\frac{k^n⋅k!⋅n!}{(n+k)!}=n!⋅\frac{k^n}{(k+1)(k+2)...(n+k)}
$$

and the last fraction, having a fixed number of $n$ factors in numerator and denominator, converges to $1$.